# RaspBMC - what is the .xbmc-current folder and why is this being used rather than .xbmc

Tags: raspbmc, kodi

I have Raspbmc and I rebooted the other night and it did and automatic upgrade, once it came back up again I had lost all my settings and it was back to default. The Advancedconfig file does not seem to be being used as my library is on a MySQL server and none of the SMB folders are being used.

I SSH'ed in and noticed there was an .xbmc-current folder sym-linked to the /opt/ folder, I renamed this to .xbmc-current_old but on next reboot this was re-created, and I still had no config.

To me it seems that the .xbmc folder is being ignored and the .xbmc-current folder used instead with default settings. I have googled and I cannot understand what this is or what is going on. I don't have nightly builds or anything like this turned on.

Can anyone explain what might be happening, what the xbmc-current folder is and how I get XBMC to go back to using my .xbmc folder again?

Many Thanks in advance,

Richard

Comment: It could be that my advancedconfig.xml file isn't being read for some reason but this doesn't explain why the '.xbmc-current' folder is being created each time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the database upgrade failed. This happened to me too, and I had to fix it manually.

See here for help: [XBMC/MySQL upgrade instructions](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=MySQL/Upgrading_XBMC#Backing_up_the_database).

In my case, I needed to grant the xbmc account the necessary access to upgrade the database:

```
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
mysql> GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'xbmc';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)
```

When I restarted XBMC, it updated the library successfully.

If that doesn't work, see the instructions [here](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=MySQL/Upgrading_XBMC#Upgrade_fails).

To answer your other questions:

- ~/.xbmc-current is a symlink to the currently installed XBMC build.
- If you install a nightly build using the raspbmc settings app, the ~/.xbmc-current symlink will be recreated to point to the nightly build.
- If you remove .xbmc-current, it will be automatically recreated to point at the default version of xbmc.
- Your user settings go in ~/.xbmc, same as always.

Comment: Thanks i just managed to ssh in enable logging and it seems the problem is with db access. I'll update privileges tonight and hope that will work. I should have checked earlier and got side tracked by a red herring.

Comment: Thanks this solved the problem the xbmc db user didn't have create grants only access to the existing DBs.

Answer (score 0):

The xbmc_current link goes to the executable files for xbmc. The xbmc folder is where your settings are stored.

It requires both folders to work.